# allows European countries to checkout openacrt

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Iam using opencart v3.0.2 , in this i want some additional feature like , allows customer to confirm the orders only for European countries , Please help anyone to add this feature in my application , Thank You.

Comment: you want only European countries to check out then disable other country

Answer (score 2):

**IF you want to allows customer to confirm the orders only for European countries**

You have to disabled others country. 
from here 
[image]

select disabled and save 
[image]

First remove the all cache files from **system/storage/cache**

**do not remove index.html**

so you will be only see the enable country only in checkout

[image]